# How to transformation photo using cloudinary _?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, cloudinary

ı have been working node js project which using cloudinary package. I uploaded images successfuly but I dont transformation ( width,height,crop e.g ) image when I show the images on the page.I tried different solutions but I couldn't find a solution. What is my mistake, please help me ...

```
import Photo from "../models/photoModel.js";
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import fs from "fs";

const createPhoto = async (req, res) => {
  const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    req.files.image.tempFilePath,
    {
      use_filename: true,
      folder: "photoNetwork",
    }
  );

  console.log("RESULT::", result);

  try {
    await Photo.create({
      name: req.body.name,
      description: req.body.description,
      user: res.locals.user._id,
      url: result.secure_url,
      image_id: result.public_id,
    });

    fs.unlinkSync(req.files.image.tempFilePath);
    res.status(201).redirect("/users/dashboard");
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      succeded: false,
      error,
    });
  }
};
**
const getAllPhotos = async (req, res) => {
  cloudinary.image(result.secure_url, {       // ı use this function but it is not working
    secure: true,
    transformation: [{ width: 600, height: 400 }],
  });
  try {
    const photos = res.locals.user
      ? await Photo.find({ user: { $ne: res.locals.user._id } })
      : await Photo.find({});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      succeded: false,
      error,
    });
  }
};
**



export { createPhoto, getAllPhotos, getAPhoto};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the public_id and not the secure URL as a param for that function.

```
  const createImageTag = (publicId, ...colors) => {

    // Set the effect color and background color
    const [effectColor, backgroundColor] = colors;

    // Create an image tag with transformations applied to the src URL
    let imageTag = cloudinary.image(publicId, {
      transformation: [
        { width: 250, height: 250, gravity: 'faces', crop: 'thumb' },
        { radius: 'max' },
        { effect: 'outline:10', color: effectColor },
        { background: backgroundColor },
      ],
    });

    return imageTag;
};
```

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_quickstart